# How to manage a list of objects?

Tags: java, android, listview, scrollview

I'd like to make an Android (I'm a beginner) application in which I can manage a list of objects (for example Animals). I need to be able to click on each animal of the list to remove it or to edit its attributes, the problem is that I have no idea how to do that.

Here is my Animal class (`animal.java`) as you can see it's really basic:

```
public class Animal {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private float size;
    private double weight;

    public Animal(String name, int age, float size, double weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.size = size;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public float getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(float size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}
```

Here is my MainActivity class (`MainActivity.java`) :

```
package fr.lap.test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.lv);

        String[] animals = new String[15];
        for (int i = 0;i < 15; i++)
            animals[i] = "animal " + i;

        final List<String> tests_list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(animals));

        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tests_list);

        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

And here is the `activity_main.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[The application result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYlAm.png)

So as you can see, I have a list of `String` with the animal "names". I found this code on the Internet but I don't really understand how everything works so I can't adapt it to make the items clickable, ...

What I would like to know is :

- in my case, is the `ListView` the better solution or using a `ScrollView` would be a better idea ?
- how make the items in the list clickable (to open a new Activity and be able to access a "control panel" of the selected item)
- how to add and remove the items of the list
- I guess I can't put the `Animals` in the list, so should I have two lists: one with `Animals` and one with their name ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I think question is too broad. 
Try to narrow down your doubts and focus on a single problem.
Explain it well, explain what you tried and you will get specific answer.
Do the same for the other doubts, if any.

On Stackoverflow we focus on simple QA structure, a question containing several questions is generally just confusing for both people answering and people looking for the answer in the future.

Good luck!

Comment: You need to learn about `RecyclerView`. There are a lot of good text and video tutorials about it so I won't explain it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use these, it is a recyclerView and it's adapter.

main xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

cell xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the Adapter class :

```
public class AnimalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AnimalAdapter.AnimalViewHolder> {


    public class AnimalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements  View.OnClickListener {

        TextView name;



        NewsItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ///do what you want when clicking on your animal object
        }

    }


    public List<Animal> animalList = new ArrayList<>();

    public AnimalAdapter(List<Animal> animalList){
        this.animalList = animalList;


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return newsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public AnimalViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View itemView;
        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cell_animal, viewGroup, false);
        return new AnimalViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AnimalViewHolder holder, int i) {

        holder.name.setText(animalList.get(i).getName());

    }



    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

}
```

your activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerView lv = findViewById(R.id.lv);

        List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0;i < 15; i++){
            ///addd your animals like:
            Animal rabbit = new Animal("rabbit",2,1,15);
            animals.add(rabbit)
          }


        lv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        lv.setAdapter(new AnimalAdapter(animals));

    }
```